# Create chart title from sheetname

Tags: excel, charts, named-ranges, vba

I am hoping to amend my charts using VBA

I have created a Named Range using formula, named it SheetNames

```
=REPLACE(GET.WORKBOOK(1),1,FIND("]",GET.WORKBOOK(1)),"")
```

Then in VBA, I was trying to change the chart title:

```
ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = Range("SheetNames").Value
```

But unsuccessful.  I tried using a formula to call teh sheet name in cell B1 and it works

```
=SheetNames
```

then in VBA using the follow and work well:

```
ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = Range("B1")
```

What could I do to make the first bit works?

Comment: You might want to be more specific with regards to why you cannot change the chart title. Is there an error message?

Answer (score 5):

Why use a formula to get the name of the sheet:

```
ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = ActiveSheet.Name
```